# Passing custom data through predefined COM interface

Tags: com, interface, reinterpret-cast

I'm using 3-rd party COM service. It's exposed from .NET assembly. There are several interfaces this service provides that actually I can use in my C++ application (using early binding). Actually I would like to know if it's possible to pass custom data through using these interfaces, i.e. for me it's not enough what these interfaces provide and I want to add some additional data/methods there (though interface is not mine thus I can't change it). Please advice if it's possible, if not might be there're some workaround (example would be very helpfull)?

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to pass custom data from my producer to my consumer through 3-rd party COM service. Might be I need to create my own interface that includes my methods and that inherites 3-rd party ISomething and use it?

Below is the code that illustrates the problem. Many thanks for your help...

1) Class that I'm using to pass data from producer to consumer (through 3-rd party COM service):

```
//ISomething is 3-rd party interface with some limited # of data and methods

//Something is my class that will be used to pass data where ISomething is asked 
//and it contains some methods that I need and they are not defined in ISomething
class Something: public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,  public IDispatch
{
private:
    bstr_t Name;
    bstr_t MyData;

public: 

    //COM map omitted

    //Method defined in ISomething
    STDMETHOD(get_Name)(BSTR * pRetVal)     
    { 
        *pRetVal = ::SysAllocString(Name);
        return S_OK;
    }
    //Method defined in ISomething
    STDMETHOD(put_Name)(BSTR pRetVal)           
    { 
        Name = pRetVal; 
        return S_OK;
    }

    **//Method that is NOT defined in ISomething**
    STDMETHOD(get_MyData)(BSTR * pRetVal)           
    { 
        MyData= pRetVal; 
        return S_OK;
    }

    **//Method that is NOT defined in ISomething**
    STDMETHOD(put_MyData)(BSTR pRetVal)         
    { 
        MyData = pRetVal; 
        return S_OK;
    }
}
```

2) My data producer fills the data and passes it to 3-rd party COM service

```
CComObject<Something> *Obj = NULL;
CComObject<Something>::CreateInstance(&Obj);

//Calling method defined in ISomething
Obj->put_Name(_bstr_t("Some data"));

**//Calling method that is NOT defined in ISomething**
Obj->put_MyData(_bstr_t("My data"));

//Passing data to COM service
CComPtr<ISomething> iObj;
Obj->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ISomething),(void **) &iObj);

CComPtr<ICommand> command = //init omitted, it's another 3-rd party object;
//Setting data
command->do(iObj);
```

3) My data consumer tries to get both defined and non-defined data but succeeds only in getting defined one, non-defined contains garbage

```
class SomethingEventSink : public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>, 
                     public IDispatch
{

    //COM map omitted

    STDMETHOD(SomethingEventHandler)(VARIANT sender, struct _SomethingEventArgs *args)  
    {

        ISomething* obj;
        Something* extObj;

        args->get_Something(&obj);

        BSTR Name, Name1, MyData;

        //Works fine
        obj->get_Name(&Name);

        //Casting to my object pointer
        extObj = reinterpret_cast<Something*>(obj)

        //Works fine
        extObj->get_Name(&Name1);

        **//Works, but NO DATA I've set at producer step**
        **//HOW TO MAKE IT WORK?**
        extObj->get_MyData(&MyData);

        return S_OK;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do isn't possible the way you are doing it.  However you may be able to get it to work if you can declare your own new interface?

In this case your object can implement ISomething & IMyInterface and you can define IMyInterface to have any new methods you want.

Comment: Thanks, a few minutes ago thought about the same. I will try and reply back.

Comment: Hi Toby, sorry for delay, I had a business trip. No it didn't, actually it was impossible from the very beginning since those are completely different objects (one that I pass to 3-rd party COM service and one that they return to me. They copy data from original object to one that they return and copy in accordance with their interface ISomething. So neither extending nor casting will help here. Many thanks for your answer in any case!